How do I get labels to show in facet wrap?
I'm trying to plot a box plot with a labelled facet wrap. I've followed a few examples on here and still can't get it to work- it keeps putting 0 and 1 on the plot headings rather than the actual labels.
dataRT$evolveto=factor(dataRT$evolveto)   # evolve to visible 1  or evolve to camo 0
evolveto.labs <- c("0" = "Camouflage", "1" ="Visible")

bar3<-ggplot(dataRT, aes(gen,contrastT, fill=fiteval)) + stat_summary(fun = mean, geom ="bar", position="dodge") +stat_summary(fun.data =mean_cl_normal, geom ="errorbar", position = position_dodge(width=0.90), width =0.2) +labs(x="generation", y="Colour Disparity", fill="Evaluation Model") + facet_wrap(~ evolveto, labeller= labeller(group = evolveto.labs)) +  labs(title = "Evolve To")
bar3


Appologies if this is obvious but I'm not getting an error and have tried a few examples (also tried Index in stead of group).  I want Camouflage and Visible at the top as opposed to 0 and 1.
Thank you.

As the name of the facetting variable is evolveto you should do labeller= labeller(evolveto = evolveto.labs) to assign your labels, e.g. try data.frame(evolveto = c(0, 1)) |> ggplot() + facet_wrap(~evolveto, labeller = labeller(evolveto = evolveto.labs))

Managed to work it out:
Had done the labels wrong:
dataRT$evolveto=factor(dataRT$evolveto, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("Camouflage", "Visible"))  

Then call the ggplot functions like this:
bar3<-ggplot(dataRT, aes(gen,contrastT, fill=fiteval)) + stat_summary(fun = mean, geom ="bar", position="dodge") +stat_summary(fun.data =mean_cl_normal, geom ="errorbar", position = position_dodge(width=0.90), width =0.2) +labs(x="generation", y="Colour Disparity", fill="Evaluation Model") + facet_wrap(~ evolveto, labeller=label_value) +  labs(title = "Evolve To")

